# Walk crawling, leaping, hopping

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I say the followings:

> Frog walks hopping.
>
> Snake walks crawling.

Are these sentences correct to use? Or simply **crawl, hop, leap?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sentences are not correct, as

> [hop](https://www.google.com/search?q=hop%20meaning&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK834PK834&oq=hop%20mean&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2727j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) means to "*move by jumping with two or all feet at once."*

and

> [walk](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK834PK834&ei=nD3BXKiEA_nYgweEgITADQ&q=walk%20meaning&oq=walk%20meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.61764.62331..62581...0.0..0.338.906.2-2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.JVdCXARfTMU) means to *"move at a regular pace by lifting and setting
>   down each foot in turn, never having both feet off the ground at
>   once."*

As you can see, both words have the same basic meaning, i.e, **to move**, so you'd be repeating similar words here, if using them both together.
So simply use crawl, hop, walk alone.

Same applies for crawl and leap too.

(On the side note, snake does not crawl, it slithers. [Source](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118090/a-comparison-between-creep-crawl-and-slither))

Comment: Can I say, "Frogs move hopping."?

Comment: No, you can not, as hopping means "to move" too. That way, you would be saying "Frogs move moving"

Comment: @Kumarsadhu You can say *frogs move **by** hopping*, but you can't drop the preposition.